# Can we integrate brownian motion with respect to a deterministic function

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $B_t$ be brownian motion at time $t$, and $x$ be some random variable.

For instance,
I know that

$$\int_0^T 1 dB_t = 1(B_T-B_0)$$

And that

$$\int_0^T \cos(B_t) dB_t$$ cannot be directly integrated,

but what about

$$\int_0^T \sin(B_t) dx$$

Can this last one be integrated, treating $$\sin(B_t)$$ as if it were a constant, and thus yielding :

$$\int_0^T \sin(B_t) dx = T\sin(B_t)$$

Comment: What do $B_t, T,x$ stand for?

Comment: @RogelioMolina $B_t$ is a Brownian motion, $T$ is just a constant $\geq 0$, $x$ is just a dummy variable as in the Riemann integral.

Comment: $B_t = $ Brownian motion at time $t$

$T= $  upper bound for the integral

$x = $ some random variable

Comment: @korlaaet I'm no expert on this topic, but have you perhaps tried using Ito and "integrating" from there? (By the way, I have wanted to know an answer to this as well.)

Comment: @korlaaet Since the integrand does not depend on $x$, the equality $$\int_0^T \sin(B_t) \, dx = \sin (B_t) T$$ does obviously hold true. Mind that this integral is different from $$\int_0^T \sin(B_t) \, dt$$ and $$\int_0^T \sin(B_t) \, dB_t.$$

Comment: Saz, can either of those last two be directly integrated ?

Comment: @elbarto Depends on what you mean by "directly integrated". If you want to find a function $f$ such that $$\int_0^T \sin(B_t) \, dt = f(B_T),$$ then the answer is "no".

Comment: thank-you everyone - my questions are all answered